# Can anyone explain "items.map((item) =>item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, arrow-functions, spread-syntax

Can anyone explain "**items.map((item) =>item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item**"?
I just came up with this kind of example, don't know if it's correct.(if "onChange={() => Check(2)"}
first loop:

```
    const listItems = items.map(({id: 1,checked: true,item: "Item 1"}) =>
      1 === 2 ? { {id: 1,checked: true,item: "Item 1"}, checked: !True } : "Item 1"
    );
```

second loop:

```
    const listItems = items.map(({id: 2,checked: true,item: "Item 2"}) =>
      2 === 2 ? { {id: 2,checked: false,item: "Item 2"}, checked: !false} : "Item 2"
    );
```

third loop:

```
    const listItems = items.map(({id: 3,checked: true,item: "Item 3"}) =>
      3 === 2 ? { {id: 3,checked: false,item: "Item 3"}, checked: !false} : "Item 3"
    );
```

Code:

```
const Content = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      checked: true,
      item: "Item 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      checked: false,
      item: "Item 2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      checked: false,
      item: "Item 3"
    }
  ]);

  const Check = (id) => {
    const listItems = items.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
    );
    setItems(listItems);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={() => Check(item.id)}
              checked={item.checked}
            />
            <label
              style={item.checked ? { textDecoration: "line-through" } : null}
              onDoubleClick={() => Check(item.id)}
            >
              {item.item}
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Comment: *"don't know if it's correct"*: first you should tell us what the intention is of the code. Only then we can tell if it does that correctly.

Comment: I would like to know what { ...item, checked: !item.checked } means and why does it work? And about the map+spread...

Comment: You should just ask one question, but this is just a standard example of [spread syntax in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).

Comment: I mean I can't understand "combined map and spread"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct but you looping through all the object every time you can reduce the complexity by using `find` or `findIndex` (what `find` and `find index` do it will return immediately when the find first matching value) when you know the id and index number but that can be changed so I assume `id` will unique

```
const Check = (givenId) => {
let updatedUserList = [...items]
const objIndex = updatedUserList.findIndex(user => user.id == givenId);
updatedUserList[objIndex].checked = !updatedUserList[objIndex].checked;
setItems(updatedUserList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`items.map((item) =>item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item"?`

1. `items.map()` you first iterate through the items array
2. `(item) => item.id === id` on every item, you check if `item.id === id`
3. `? { ...item, checked: !item.checked }` if the `item.id checks id` then you reverse the value of `item.checked`, if not then you let it be

If your intention was to reverse the checked box or wtv based on its id then this code must be the thing you want!

Comment: So, the 3.  ...item = {id: 1,checked: true,item: "Item 1"}?

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean but imagine if you have 3 boxes, each with an id,

if you click on box 2, your algorithm will check all boxes and when it hits box 2: `box.id === id` and then it reverses its property of `checked: false` to `checked: true`